# Adding citing list and my own publications

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I know this has been published several times, however the solutions I found did not work for me, and I do not even know why. I would like to add first a list of publication cited on the text and after a list of my own publications, which are, or  not cited in the text.
Here what I did so far:

First file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,refsection=section]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\include{doc1}
\include{doc2}
\end{document
```

Doc1:

```
Here a wrote my citations \cite{citation1} and others \cite{citation2}
\printbibliography
```

Doc2:

```
\section{My publications}
\printbibliography[{keyword={own}, title=none}\
```

What am I doing wrong? I obtain allways a message error, saying: Keyword own not found

As an example of my bibliography.bib file here you have a sample:

```
@article{mypub1,
  title={Title 2},
  author={Ruiz},
  journal={Applied Physics B},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Publisher},
  keyword= {own},
}

@article{mypub2,
  title={title2},
  author={Ruiz},
  journal={Physica Scripta},
  volume={2014},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2014},
  publisher={ublishing},
  keyword= {own},
}
@article{citation2,
  title={Title2},
  author={Author1},
  journal={Optics},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Publisher}
}


@article{citation1,
  title={Title2},
  author={Author1},
  journal={Optics},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The field for keywords is `keywords` and not `keyword`. Also as you put every section in a refsection with `refsection=section` they build an unit of their own, so you must add cite commands to the second section to see something.

```
\begin{filecontents}{testown.bib}
@article{mypub1,
  title={Title 2},
  author={Ruiz},
  journal={Applied Physics B},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Publisher},
  keywords= {own},
}

@article{mypub2,
  title={title2},
  author={Ruiz},
  journal={Physica Scripta},
  volume={2014},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2014},
  publisher={ublishing},
  keywords= {own},
}
@article{citation2,
  title={Title2},
  author={Author1},
  journal={Optics},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Publisher}
}


@article{citation1,
  title={Title2},
  author={Author1},
  journal={Optics},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,refsection=section]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testown.bib}
\begin{document}
Here a wrote my citations \cite{citation1} and others \cite{citation2}
\printbibliography
\section{My publications}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword={own}, heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]